# MacOS source ~/.bash_profile disabled everything

Tags: macos, operating-system, go, environment-variables, bash

So I was trying to setup the Go programming environment on my Mac and add the necessary directory to the path by modifying the .bash_profile accordingly. After saving the .bash_profile, I tried running "go version" for example but it still didn't work.

After a bit of searching I found that if i did the following:
source ~/.bash_profile

The go version would work. Which it does but it seems that my PATH has been changed since commands such as: nano, vi, ls, sudo etc do not work anymore.

Is there a way of recuperating my initial environment PATH?

Thanks in advance!!
:D

PS - let me know if my issue is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Note that your path is likely just "broken" for your current shell session: Mac OS X doesn't strictly use .bash_profile for your PATH.

My guess is that you didn't write out `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` and `export GOPATH=/Users/sSmacKk/go/` (or wherever you wanted to set it) correctly: if you forget to assign the existing path back to your new path, you'll have problems.

1. Run `path_helper` from `/usr/libexec/path_helper` (which would normally be on your path!)
2. Add the lines: `export GOPATH=/wherever/you/want/` and then `export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin` to your `.bash_profile`
3. Save and exit from your text editor and then `source .bash_profile`.